# Adding ChildViewControllers not adjusted space in UIStackView dynamically with its content

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to add child view controllers to the container view with the `UIStackView`.
Views were added but the content size is not the same that I expected from its child view controllers.

I have 2 views `SecondViewController` and `ThirdViewController` added to the `ContainerViewController` as child-view-controllers. But the views are not aligned as expectedly.

```swift
// ViewController
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @IBAction func show() {
        let continer = ContainerViewController()
        self.present(continer, animated: true)
    }
}
// ContainerViewController

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private lazy var contentStackView: UIStackView = {
        let view = UIStackView()
        view.axis = .vertical
        view.spacing = 16.0
        return view
    }()
    
    override func loadView() {
        let mainView = UIView()
        mainView.addSubview(self.contentStackView)
        let views =  [SecondViewController(), ThirdViewController()]
        
        _ = views.map { child in
            child.willMove(toParent: self)
            addChild(child)
            contentStackView.addArrangedSubview(child.view)
            child.didMove(toParent: self)
        }
        self.view = mainView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        contentStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            contentStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            contentStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            contentStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor)
        ])

    }
    
    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("\(#function) has not been implemented")
    }
}

// SecondViewController

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    var blackView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .black
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(blackView)
        blackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.top.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(100)
        }
    }
    
    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("\(#function) has not been implemented")
    }
}


class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var redView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .red
        return view
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.addSubview(redView)
        redView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.leading.top.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(100)
        }
    }
    
    public init() {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    @available(*, unavailable)
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("\(#function) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

With the above code, I want to show back and red views with a `100 px` height. Ideally, ever the content is there with the children's view controllers.

Here we can see the current output.

[image: Gif example]

Thanks in advance.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`make.leading.top.trailing.equalToSuperview()` should be replaced to `make.edges.equalToSuperview()` to help controllers' views to calculate their size. With only three sides constrained, they can't understand that they have to match the coloured views' heights.
Also, if the task is to display these two controllers with fixed heights, here probably should be another bottom sheet, matching its content size, or a flexible bottom constraint for the stack view, to take less space than available when the content is small.

Comment: Thanks @dmc for your input, As you said It's an issue with UIStackView content,
Here I just updated the bottom constraints as below.

```swift
            contentStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: -16)
 ```